# Disable Product Reviews but keep rating enabled

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, review

I would like to disable the review option on product page in magento CE 1.9.0.1 but like to keep rating feature.
I tried "Go to System>Configuration>Advance>mage_review >disable, but it then disables the rating also.

Also disabling mage_review takes off the Reviews and Rating tabs under catalog, which can be understood. But Ratings goes off with it too.

I would like to know the workaround over this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that when you disable `Mage_Review` then `Mage_Rating` also gets disabled.

You can manually remove the review form by editing the following template file:

`app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/review/form.phtml`

The review form is submitted to `postAction()` of class `Mage_Review_ProductController` (`app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php`).

Comment: This is what i was asking,  thanks for the postAction() hint. I was exactly asking the same post action url as where the data get submitted 
Thanks  again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using the Ratings but not the reviews you might need to modify your phtml to remove or hide the Leave a review form. Dont remove the entire block from the XML since that will remove the stars you want to keep.

Here is a small [guide](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/customised-review-summary) to achieve something similar, this is the code for a short review output in the List/Grid view:

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, "short", true)?>
```

Comment: is '/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/review/form.phtml' correct file to edit? and for the safe side can i just comment the form code following the '<ul class="form-list">' ?

Comment: I dont have a lot of experience in frontend, but i would say that is the correct phtml to edit to achieve this.

Comment: so i went ahead and applied comment. Now i wud like to know which file handles the submitted data from review form , since without removing review input validations i will not succeed. Thank You.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. I dont think i understand you.

Comment: sorry if m not clear, the question is which file handles submitted form data from the review form presemt at  '/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/review/form.phtml'
I Cant find the filename in action attribute `<form action="<?php echo $this->getAction() ?>"`
Thanks

Comment: I believe there are two different modules for Review and Ratings, so why not to simply disable Mage_Review and keep the Mage_Rating as it is? I've never done that, but worth a try, isn't it?